# Add JavaScript inside controller

Tags: 8, javascript, page-controller

How to add JavaScript inside controller? I don't want to call build form. I can call css or js in `src/Form/Form.php` but I want to call css or js inside Controller `src/Controller/Controller.php`
This process I am using to call css and js in Form page

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state,$cid = NULL)
{

$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'cssjs/val_master';

}
```

Could anyone write some example to call css or js inside Controller

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same you can use in Controller also:

```
<?php

   namespace Drupal\cssjs\Controller;

   use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

   class CssJs extends ControllerBase{
     public function css_js(){
       $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'cssjs/val_master';
       return $build;
     }

   }
```